# Program will return occurrences

Tags: java, count, return

```
public class one {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String one = "lmao";
    char a = 'm';

    System.out.println(occurrences(one, a));
  }

  public static int occurrences(String s, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    s = "lol";
    c = 'l';
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get this program to output the number of occurrences of a character. I want it to output what is in main but it keeps outputting what is in the method occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following two lines, which are overriding the values of the variables that are being passed in from the `main()` function:

```
    s = "lol";
    c = 'l';
```

Comment: @EdwardLavaire so please mark this answer as "accepted" so it doesn't show in open questions. Thanks! :)